# Django redirect from form to view in a different app

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect, view

I have a django form that is now useless. I would like to always redirect from that form to a view in a different app.

Here's what I have:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("management:management_account_add_user"))
```

But I'm not sure where to put it.

Answer (score 0):

Hang in there!   It's not useless yet…

to get it to redirect no matter what:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from utils.urlencoders import reverse

def view():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name_registered_in_settings.py:view_name_registered_in_urls.py'))
  # GET
  else:
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name_registered_in_settings.py:view_name_registered_in_urls.py'))
```

and/or in your template, if you have access to the submit, you can :

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'app_name_registered_in_settings.py:view_name_registered_in_urls.py' %}">
```

Note: In general, You would want to provide a bit more context/code to help others help you.

Comment: The form can only be accessed from the admin interface for the app. There is no view for it.  it is called UserCreationForm